# Individually display items from an array in the Google Apps Script sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a responsive sidebar for processing orders by displaying items from an array one at a time.

Ideally, one item is displayed and the user can choose from three separate actions: Previous, Select, and Next.

The information in the array is pulled from order data within the workbook, this isn't the exact code I'm using but its written to present the same functionality:

```
function pullData() {
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const column = {
    orderNumber: 1,
    customerName: 2,
    quantityOrdered: 3
  }

  // finding all instances of orders for product ID: XY1234
  const productId = 'XY1234';
  const orders = sheet.createTextFinder(productId).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  // array to store all orders for this product
  const orderInfo = new Array();
  orders.forEach(order => {

    // collecting order info
    let row = order.getRow()
    let orderNumber = sheet.getRange(row, column.orderNumber);
    let customerName = sheet.getRange(row, column.customerName);
    let quantityOrdered = sheet.getRange(row, column.quantityOrdered);

    // combining the order info into a list item
    let thisOrder = `
      Order number: ${orderNumber} 
      Customer name: ${customerName} 
      Quantity ordered: ${quantityOrdered}`;

    orderInfo.push(thisOrder);

  });
}
```

and this is a simple idea of the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      div.listContent {
        margin-left: 15%;
        text-align: left;
      }
      div.buttons {
        margin: auto 10% auto 10%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        ailgn-items: center;
      }
      .input {
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="listContent">
      <!-- this is how orderInfo[x] would be displayed, formatting aside -->
      <p>
         Order number: [order number]<br>
         Customer name: [customer name]<br>
         Quantity ordered: [quantity ordered]
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input class="input" type="button" onclick="" value="Previous">
      <input class="input" type="button" onclick="" value="Select">
      <input class="input" type="button" onclick="" value="Next">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I lack knowledge in frontend at the moment &, given that I haven't been able to display different items from orderInfo to the sidebar, I haven't been able to troubleshoot ideas.

My current thoughts are decrementing the index in orderInfo when the "Previous" button is clicked and incrementing the index respectively; however that's neither here nor there for now.

The program is written modularly so I've tried some other individual functions but the problem with each attempt is that I can't just insert a variable from a .gs file to the HTML without it being written into the HTML.

I'll update if I figure it out

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you struggling with? How did you populate the data of the sidebar and enable the communication between the fornt and backend so far (disregarding the next / previous functionality)? Are you evaluating a [template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) or using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add id to some tag, e.g. <p id="content"> and change it dynamically using innerHtml.

And you can pass data from GAS into javascript with plain JSON conversion, something like this

In html

```
  ...
  <div class="listContent">
    <!-- this is how orderInfo[x] would be displayed, formatting aside -->
    <p id="content"> <!-- NOTICE ID ADDED !!! -->
  ...
  <input class="input" type="button" onclick="next" value="Next">
  <input class="input" type="button" onclick="prev" value="Prev">
  <input class="input" type="button" onclick="select" value="Select">
  ...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var index = 0;
  var data = JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(data) ?>
  function next() {
    if(index<data.length - 1) index++;
    setContent();
  }
  function prev() {
    if(index>0) index--;
    setContent();
  }
  function select() {
    // Whatever
  }
  function setContent() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHtml = data[index];
  }
</script>
```

In apps script:

While template rendering add appropriate data from spreadsheet, as simple array, for example

```
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

template.data = pullData();

return template.evaluate().getContent()
```

You also need to update your pullData to return value in the end

```
  ...
  return orderInfo;
}
```

Comment: So I understand now that I had it backwards; I need to send the data from GAS rather than fetch it from HTML. I have the HTML portion understood now but, for the apps script portion, can that be wrapped in a function? & if so, is `template.evaluate().getcontent()` the HtmlOutput for the sidebar? I'm playing around with the code right now but I feel like I'm still missing something obvious. On top of that do you know of a good resource I can use to better understand what happening here?

Comment: Yes. All of this is described in a lot of examples in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates . You use templates to pass data from apps script.